# Intune Remediation detection script issue

Tags: powershell, intune

I have Remediation script to detect any installations of an app on our estate.  It is known to be installed in one of two locations:

1. C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\App\bin\App.exe
   or
2. C:\Program Files\App\bin\App.exe

The issue I have is my detection script is not picking up an installation in the first install location, even though it is installed.
This is the script I'm using:

```
Try
{
 $LocalAppData = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\AppData\"
$AppPath =  $LocalAppData +"roaming\*App*\bin\"
$EXEPath = $AppPath +"*App*.exe"
$LocalAppData2 = "C:\Program Files"
$AppPath2 =  $LocalAppData2 +"\*App*\bin\"
$EXEPath2 = $AppPath2 +"*App*.exe"     
If ($(Test-Path -Path $EXEPath) -eq $True) {
    Write-Host "*App* is installed in Roaming Folder"
    exit 1
    }
elseif 
    ($(Test-Path -Path $EXEPath2) -eq $True) {
    Write-Host "*App* is installed in Program Files"
Exit 1
}
else
{
    #No remediation required    
    Write-Host "*App* is not installed"
    exit 0
}  
}

    catch {
        $errMsg = $_.Exception.Message
        Write-Error $errMsg
        # exit 1
    }
```

Running the script in Powershell displays that the app is installed - as expected

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Why would the elseif statement work for those with it installed in that location if that has exit 1 and then kick in the remediation script to perform the requirements and feedback correctly?

Comment: your script is running in system context ?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking there. Basically, only return 1 if you need to remediate. `The detection script must use exit code exit 1 if the target issue is detected. The remediation script won't run when there's any other exit code, including an empty output, since it results in an issue is not found state'`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/fundamentals/powershell-scripts-remediation

Answer (score 0):

You must set "Run this script using the logged-on credentials" to Yes